# Store the data of deleted record using trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g

I want to write a trigger which fires on deletion of a record from a table, and inserts a record in another table and uses the details of the record deleted.

> Database : Oracle 10g

My trigger looked like this

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER myTrigger
AFTER DELETE
    ON myTable
    REFERENCING NEW AS old_tab
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ACTIVITYLOG values ('ADMIN',:old_tab.tabletID,'MIGRATION','ERROR','TEST','T','NIL',sysdate)
END;
```

here `:old_tab.tabletID` the `tabletID` is the column of the table `myTable` in which deletion is done.
I want to save the I and a log that it was deleted.

But when I try deleting a record I get the following error

> Error code 4098, SQL state 42000: ORA-04098: trigger 'DB.MYTRIGGER' is
>   invalid and failed re-validation
>
> **P.S. Ran the trigger creation in NetBeans SQL Editor.**

Here is the,

> **EDIT**

**STRUCTURE OF** `myTable` **(Table deletion occurs)**

```
tabletID varchar2(15) PRIMARY KEY
tabletName varchar2(100)
```

**STRUCTURE OF** `ACTIVITYLOG`

```
username varchar2(15)
tabletKey varchar2(15)
page_ref varchar2(100)
errors varchar2(100)
remarks varchar2(100)
operationcode char(2)
lastupdateip varchar2(20)
lastupdatedate date
```

Sorry don't have access to SQL PLUS EDITOR.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a semicolon after insert statement?

Comment: @MarcinWroblewski I got the the error `Error code 900, SQL state 42000: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement` when tried creating the trigger with semicolon. 

Also I tried creating the trigger from the Netbeans SQL editor

Comment: Show us the definition of both tables so that we can reproduce the error. By the way - "REFERENCING NEW AS old_tab"?

Comment: @MarcinWroblewski Added the structure of the tables for reference.

Comment: When you created the trigger, did you terminate it with a `/`? I'm not familiar with NetBeans IDE, but in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer you need that to tell it to execute the code block. You do need the `;` after the `insert`, the ORA-900 seems to suggest it doesn't understand the block at all maybe, although (sometimes) the trigger is created with errors. Try doing 'show errors trigger my trigger' and see if that tells what's actually wrong with it. You should also list the columns in the `insert`, not assume they will always be in that order.

Comment: @MarcinWroblewski you were right it needed a `semicolon`, but for some reason `Netbeans` gave me an error when I did that.

@AlexPoole Yeah `SQL Plus` did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
REFERENCING NEW AS old_tab
```

You've redefined the NEW values with the label "old_tab". This is somewhat like adding `#define FALSE TRUE` to the top of a program.

Add a `semicolon` after the insert statement

Because you're using an AFTER DELETE trigger, you only need to access the :OLD values, e.g.:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER myTrigger
AFTER DELETE
    ON myTable
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ACTIVITYLOG values ('ADMIN',:OLD.tabletID,'MIGRATION','ERROR','TEST','T','NIL',sysdate);
END;
```

Comment: Apart from all I also removed the `REFERENCING NEW AS old_tab` which helped...But I did use the `BEFORE DELETE` option

@Jeffrey Yours was the nearest answer, Just add the semicolon at the end of the insert query, so it becomes syntactically correct...and I could accept and answer.

Comment: You can use the `BEFORE DELETE` or `AFTER DELETE`, both will work for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the :OLD values rather than the :NEW values.  The :NEW values in a DELETE trigger (whether BEFORE or AFTER) are blank.   This makes sense, because if you think about it the record has logically ceased to exist at this point.

However that is not a source of compilation errors.

> "still the same error shows up on deletion. "

I suppose we could spend all day guessing what's wrong so let's stop now.  You can discover the compilation errors with this simple query:

```
select * from user_errors
where name = 'MYTRIGGER'
and type = 'TRIGGER'
```

---

> "I changed the :NEW to :OLD, and added a semicolan and ran it on SQL
>   PLUS, and that did the trick"

For the benefit of future here is a version of the trigger which will compile and which will correctly write the required values:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER myTrigger 
AFTER DELETE 
    ON myTable 
    REFERENCING OLD AS old_tab 
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO ACTIVITYLOG values ('ADMIN',:old_tab.tabletID,'MIGRATION','ERROR','TEST','T','NIL',sysdate); 
END; 
/
```

Comment: I tried changing it to `BEFORE` and also referencing `:NEW` but still the same error shows up on deletion. 

Added the structure of the tables for reference.

Comment: APC, I'm surprised at you! An AFTER trigger *does* have access to the old values of the record that has been deleted.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - the OP is using the NEW values of the record.  Which are *blank* when referenced in an AFTER trigger.  So that's definitely wrong, but I agree not a source of compilation errors.

Comment: @APC I changed the `:NEW` to `:OLD`, and added a `semicolan` and ran it on `SQL PLUS`, and that did the trick....

Sort of a combined work of the answer and comments solved this. 

Main problem was I was trying it from a `Netbeans` editor and it didnt take the semicolon, SQL plus did...

Comment: +1 @APC - yes, I was reacting to your original statement "If you think about it, that means the record (logically) doesn't exist." - your edits make your thinking much clearer in this regard.